# File Upload Module in Apache2 Ubuntu

Tags: upload, apache2, cgi, linux-mint

I'm a newcomer/hobbyist so go easy on me. I have searched and experimented quite a bit before asking.

System: Linux-mint-14-KDE (based on Ubuntu 12.10)

Server: Apache2 installed via sudo apt-get install apache2

My goal was to be able to allow remote users to upload files, via a form, to a directory.

from this site: commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="fup.cgi">
  File to upload: <input type="file" name="upfile"><br/>
  Notes about the file: <input type="text" name="note"><br/>
  <br/>
  <input type="submit" value="Press"> to upload the file!
</form>
```

I added this code to index.html and the form shows up OK. When you go to upload files, it returns: **The requested URL /fup.cgi was not found on this server.**

The Apache2 documentation is hard to follow. To /etc/apache2/sites-available I added one part about CGI

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews ExecCGI
    AllowOverride Authconfig
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

Am I supposed to have a script file called fup.CGI? Doesn't apache2 have modules to do it for you?

All I want to do is let users upload files and cap them at, say, 5 GB. This may turn out to be too hard but I'll read and try whatever is suggested.

UPDATE

I got it to  work with CGI and perl
http://www.sitepoint.com/uploading-files-cgi-perl/